# Return a regular array instead of Observable<T[]> in RxJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs, observable

New to observables. How do I return a regular array from this function instead of an observable?

```
removeRewards(userId: string): string[] {
  return this.getUsedRewards(userId).pipe(
  switchMap(rewards => rewards.filter(reward => reward.active)),
  map(reward => reward.rewardId),
  toArray()
  );
}
```

getUsedRewards returns an Observable. I'm calling removeRewards in a different function and just  need this to return string[] instead of Observable<string[]>.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must END the stream and then use `toArray()` to achieve your goal
You can see [this example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray)

"get values emitted by interval as an array when interval **completes**"

```
// RxJS v6+
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { toArray, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

interval(100)
  .pipe(take(10), toArray())
  .subscribe(console.log);

// output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So u can do something like:

```
removeRewards(userId: string): string[] {
  return this.getUsedRewards(userId).pipe(
  switchMap(rewards => rewards.filter(reward => reward.active)),
  map(reward => reward.rewardId),
  take(1), // <-- ADD THIS LINE
  toArray()
  );
}
```

Also possible operator is `first()`

Comment: was this helpful ?

Answer (score -1):

If it is an observable, you have to subscribe it to get whatever observable emits and then use it in whatever way you want.

Comment: so If I am calling this function like const removedRewards = removeRewards(userId).subscribe(rewardIds => rewardIds) , this should work? It keeps telliing me that it is a subscription and not an array of strings.

Comment: This is an asynchronous pattern and you are trying to use it in a synchronous manner which is not correct. Do whatever you want with your array where you get `rewardIds`

Comment: I understand what you are saying, there is now equivalent like await ? Wait till I have the completed stream and then use that however?

Comment: you can use that,I think you will have to convert the observable to promise and then use it.

Comment: @sayayin pls accept the answer if it answers your queries.